# Android: Audio Matching (Audio Fingerprinting)

Tags: android, audio-fingerprinting

I'm writing an android app that plays an audio file and records what the phone is outputting simultaneously. When the recording is done, it would compare the recording against the original audio played and return whether they match and to what certainty.

I searched a lot and I found some libraries for audio fingerprinting, but they're mostly for music identification purposes.

Is there any libraries out there that I could use for this purpose? Would it make sense to write a custom algorithm for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could compare the sound waves sample to sample (as numbers), then compute maximal, minimal, average difference, etc..

Comment: Would it be okay if this is done on the user's phone or is it too much processing? If yes, would you recommend doing it on the main thread or separate thread?

Comment: It's not too much processing, phone should be ok with that. Separate thread is definitely better option.

Comment: Thank you! Could you recommend any source that is relevant to this?

Comment: Don't know exactly, but you can look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236522/audiorecord-records-intermittent-sound-in-android-l-developer-preview